# How to set up a shared folder for office

Tags: windows-xp, network-share

Work at a small 3 person company that has 4 computers(windows xp) set up behind a single router. We have a  few files that we share between us on a daily basis and currently have to walk from office to office with a usb drive to share these files. I've been at offices were we had a shared folder on one computer, and mapped that folder as a network drive on the other computers. Does anyone know how we can set this up for our office?

Comment: Your computer can answer that for you. Click the Start button, followed by "Help and Support". Then search for "file sharing", or whatever else you may be interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First share out the folder

http://www.lostintechnology.com/how-to/how-to-share-a-folder-over-a-network

Then map the folder to a drive letter

http://www.lostintechnology.com/how-to/how-to-map-a-network-drive-or-folder